# How do you keep the silent part of a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, premiere, video-editor, final-cut-pro-x

How can I keep the funny silent part of a video (sniffs, breathing,...)?
I found a solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQ8orIurGxw&t=354s), but is there another solution?
I mean: Can I do the same in a video editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to video Stack Exchange. This is an interesting question, and one that I have asked myself in the past!

- If you are willing to spend money, check out the third-party Adobe plugin [Awkward Pause](https://aescripts.com/awkward-pause/) ([click here for demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot3WgEtSrhM)).
- For a quick and dirty solution, you can try using [this command-line tool I made last semester for a class](https://github.com/evnb/vwrt). It is different from carykh's in the practical sense that it does not need to store png sequences of the images. (Therefore it requires less space.)

  - For your purposes: keep the `first_speed = 1.0` and change the `second_speed` to a very high number, then compile in XCode.

Comment: One more question: How do you run it? Do you run it in terminal?

Comment: _If you have trouble, try the following: 1) [Make sure you have ffmpeg installed](https://superuser.com/questions/624561/install-ffmpeg-on-os-x) 2) [Make sure ffmpeg is in your PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are) 3) Make sure all the file names & directories you use have no spaces 4) If you have problems on windows/linux, try using a mac (the tool should work on anywhere you compile for but I only tested it on mac.)_ I will update the readme with this info. :)

Comment: @FrodóZsákos Yes. Once you have a compiled executable file, put it in a folder with the input video. Then you can run it from terminal in that directory with `./vidsum inputvideoname.mp4 outputvideoname.mp4`

Comment: When I try to run ffmpeg this happens: `ffmpeg: command not found` can you help me with this one please?

Comment: @FrodóZsákos it sounds like either you don't have ffmpeg installed or it's not in your PATH. please follow the instructions in my other comment on this thread.